# Что за самостаятельная часть речи которая заминяет существительное прилагательное числительно и тик

Tags: орфоэпия

что за самостаятельная часть речи которая заминяет существительное прилагательное числительно и тик

Comment: Судя по Вашей грамотности, поздравляю с началом нового учебного года.

Comment: Тик - это у учителки...

Comment: И метка чудная. Орфоэпия-то тут при чем?

Answer (score 3):

Похоже Вы имеете в виду местоимение, но что такое "тик" у Вас непонятно.